How do I run a Gatsby project without downgrading my global packages?
I just got a new project updating the UI of someone's website.  I cloned the repository and went to install the packages via npm install and am running into errors because it's a Gatsby 5.12.11 project that uses react 18.12.0 while my computer has Gatsby 5.13.3 and React 18.3.1.  The project also uses Material UI 5.2.5 which depends on react ^17.0.0 and throws an error because it finds 18.3.1 which I find odd because the ^ means 'this version or higher' if I'm not mistaking.
I'd rather not delete my up to date versions Gatsby and React to in turn install older versions if I don't have to and because it's not my project it's not my place to update all their packages to suit my machine.  Is there a way for me install and run them locally in this project without having to bother with my global versions?
